# Compatibility for buttons and controllers?

Tags: ps3, ps4, controllers

My R2 button on my PS4 controller broke. Is it possible to use a trigger from a PS3 controller for it? My cousin has an extra PS3 controller that the joy sticks broke on so if I could harvest the button it would be convenient.

Comment: I can't disassamble the particular controllers at the moment to verify, but it is unlikely that they are interchangable. The shape is different and the DS3 trigger seems to be a bit wider. Also this can only work if the electrical side and the membrane of your DS4 are fully intact and you would only be changing the mechanical part.

Comment: Ok. I didnt think they would be. He messaged me saying I could use it. The trigger is held in by 2 prongs and 1 of them broke. The rest of the controller is fine. It's just that little stupid piece. But I found the button repair kit that even comes with new joysticks at walmart.com for like 8 dollars

Comment: @DoughBoiJay it might be worthwhile to add exactly what is wrong with the trigger mechanism - electronically is one thing - a spring or something like that is another.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to say what exactly is broken with this trigger. If you replace the plastic knob, then it is possible that the trigger will still not working.

I suggest you buy a new controller, even not branded by Sony if you don't have enough money.

Comment: I personally do not know of any positive experiences with 3rd party controllers but do what you need.

Comment: I also think that Sony controllers are the best choice, but some cheaper controllers also are very ergonomic.